# How to fix/clean perforce project file size as its larger than local disk size?

Tags: perforce

I have a perforce server hosted by digitalocean. Typing p4 diskspace says I'm using 45.5GB used. The same folder on my pc's size is only 26GB. I'm the only one using this server and I only have 1 workspace/project. This is an Unreal Engine 5 project.

Why would the perforce repo be almost double the size on my computer? I tried using `p4 clean` but it doesn't do anything. Running the clean action in p4v GUI client did nothing either, besides delete some local files.

Is there a way to fix the project from getting too large on the server or anything I can do to reclaim some space?

Answer (score 1):

Have you submitted multiple versions of any of your files? The server stores compressed versions of every revision of every file you have submitted, so that you can go back to those previous revisions if you ever need to. So it is natural and expected that your server storage will be larger than your local storage as a project progresses.

There are a few things you can do to make sure you aren't using more disk space than needed, though.

1. If you have ever submitted files in the wrong place and deleted them, that previous copy you deleted will still exist on the server (by default all history will be retained). It is possible to completely remove files and all their history from the server with the command `p4 obliterate`. Be warned that obliterating is permanent, so use with caution. [p4 obliterate docs](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_obliterate.html) In this case, say you uploaded a bunch of files to //myDepot/wrongFolder/... then you deleted them and re-submitted to //myDepot/rightFolder/... those previous ones still exist on the server. So you could use `p4 obliterate -y //myDepot/wrongFolder/...` to completely remove those files and all of their history from the server.
2. If you want to keep storage to a minimum and you have some specific large files, you may want to set their file type so that the server only stores a limited number of revisions for that file, instead of storing all of them. From P4V you can right click on a file and choose **Change Filetype...** then on the filetype menu, look at the +S option at the bottom, which lets you set a max number of revisions that will be kept on the server. (for example, if that is set to +S2, the server will only keep the latest two revisions and the next time you submit a revision of that file, it will delete anything before that off the server).
   Once you've changed the filetype, you can submit in order to send those changes to the server.
3. This one is specific to Digital Ocean: By default Digital Ocean wants to store everything on the main system disk of your server to keep things simple. However, this means that to expand that disk space you also need to upgrade your droplet type, which can get unnecessarily expensive. Instead, you can add a separate storage volume, which is overall much cheaper (about $1/10GB/mo.)
   I have a repo with some scripts to help automate the process of adding a volume, moving all the files to it, and resetting the server so it will use that new location. https://github.com/jase-perf/perforce-digital-ocean-helper-scripts
4. This option is much more advanced: If you update your server to the latest version of Helix Core (p4d) there is support for setting up archive depots that use s3 storage (called "Spaces" on Digital Ocean). This gives you a way to archive older files that you don't need to access but don't want to permanently delete and store them on much cheaper (but slower) S3 storage. I'm currently working on some YT videos about how to do that in detail, but you can currently read about it in the [Server Admin Guide](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/archiving-files.html), if that option seems appealing to you.